# How to validate input on overloaded constructors?

Tags: c#, constructor-overloading

Here is my code

```
public class MyClass
{
    int LeftPoints;
    int RightPoints;

    public MyClass(int points)
        : this (points, points)
    {
        if (points < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("points must be positive");
    }

    public MyClass(int leftPoints, int rightPoints)
    {
        if (leftPoints < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("leftPoints must be positive");
        if (rightPoints < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rightPoints must be positive");
    }
}
```

It is obvious that if I call `new MyClass(-1)` it throws the message "leftPoints must be positive".

It is possible to overload the first constructor using `: this (points, points)` and still get "the right" validation?

Comment: You could compile both exceptions together then throw an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why don't you use an unsigned int `public MyClass(uint points)` then it will only be positive anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve that by calling the second constructor from the first one.

If it's code reuse, you're after, you can take a different approach:

```
public MyClass(int points)
{
    if (points < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("points must be positive");
    Init(points, points);
}

public MyClass(int leftPoints, int rightPoints)
{
    if (leftPoints < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("leftPoints must be positive");
    if (rightPoints < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rightPoints must be positive");
    Init(leftPoints, rightPoints);
}

private void Init(int leftPoints, int rightPoints)
{
    LeftPoints = leftPoints;
    RightPoints = rightPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You have declared that `new MyClass(-1)` is the same thing as `new MyClass(-1,-1)` followed by the code of the `MyClass(int)` constructor. That's exactly what you got.